# Common sub-expression elimination using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, codegen

I am trying to learn using sympy to optimize the numerical evaluation of mathematical expressions in C. On one side  I know that sympy can generate C code to evaluate one expression as follows:

```
from mpmath import *
from sympy.utilities.codegen import codegen
from sympy  import *

x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
[(c_name, c_code), (h_name, c_header)] = codegen([('x', sin(x))], 'C')
```

and then you can print c_code to the destination file. On the other side, I know that cse can be used to simplify expressions as follows:

```
from mpmath import *
from sympy.utilities.codegen import codegen
from sympy  import *

x,y,z, B1, B2, B3, B4 = symbols('x y z B1 B2 B3 B4 ')
cse([3.0*B2 + 8.0*B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + 4.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + B3*z**2 + B4*x**4 + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2, 7.0*B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + y**2) + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2, B3*x*y + 8.0*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + z**2) + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + B3*x*z + 8.0*B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*y**4 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2, B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + 6.0*B3*y*z + B3*(y**2 + z**2) + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + B3*x*y + 3.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + 8.0*B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3 + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3 + B4*z**4])
```

getting as output:

```
([(x0, z**2),
  (x1, B3*x0),
  (x2, B3*x),
  (x3, x2*y),
  (x4, 3.0*x3),
  (x5, 3.0*B2),
  (x6, y**2),
  (x7, B3*x6),
  (x8, x2*z),
  (x9, x**2),
  (x10, B3*x9),
  (x11, B4*x**3),
  (x12, x11*y),
  (x13, x11*z),
  (x14, B4*y),
  (x15, x14*x9*z),
  (x16, B4*x9),
  (x17, x16*x6),
  (x18, x0*x16),
  (x19, 2*x8),
  (x20, y**3),
  (x21, B4*x),
  (x22, x20*x21),
  (x23, x0*x21*y),
  (x24, x21*x6*z),
  (x25, z**3),
  (x26, x21*x25),
  (x27, B3*y*z),
  (x28, x10 + 3.0*x27),
  (x29, B4*x20*z),
  (x30, B4*x0*x6),
  (x31, x14*x25)],
 [B4*x**4 + x1 + 8.0*x10 + x12 + x13 + x15 + x17 + x18 + x4 + x5 + x7 + 4.0*x8,
  B3*(x6 + x9) + x12 + x15 + x17 + x19 + x22 + x23 + x24 + 7.0*x3,
  B3*(x0 + x9) + x13 + x15 + x18 + x23 + x24 + x26 + x3 + 8.0*x8,
  B4*y**4 + x1 + x17 + x22 + x24 + x28 + x29 + x30 + x4 + x5 + 8.0*x7 + x8,
  B3*(x0 + x6) + x15 + x19 + x23 + x24 + 6.0*x27 + x29 + x3 + x30 + x31,
  B4*z**4 + 8.0*x1 + x18 + x23 + x26 + x28 + x3 + x30 + x31 + x5 + x7 + 3.0*x8])
```

My question is how to transform properly the  former result in C code? sometimes can be  useful to transform the reduced expressions in strings and operate on such strings, how it can be done? The aim is automatize the process of generation of code after CSE in order to apply it on many expressions.

EDIT:

Based in the answer below, thanks to Wrzlprmft, the code to produce the corresponding C code  snippet is:

```
from sympy.printing import ccode
from sympy import symbols, cse, numbered_symbols

x,y,z, B1, B2, B3, B4 = symbols('x y z B1 B2 B3 B4 ')
results = [3.0*B2 + 8.0*B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + 4.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + B3*z**2 + B4*x**4 + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2, 7.0*B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + y**2) + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2, B3*x*y + 8.0*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + z**2) + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + B3*x*z + 8.0*B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*y**4 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2, B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + 6.0*B3*y*z + B3*(y**2 + z**2) + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + B3*x*y + 3.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + 8.0*B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3 + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3 + B4*z**4]
CSE_results = cse(results,numbered_symbols("helper_"))

with open("snippet.c", "w") as output:
    for helper in CSE_results[0]:
        output.write("double ")
        output.write(ccode(helper[1],helper[0]))
        output.write("\n")

    for i,result in enumerate(CSE_results[1]):
        output.write(ccode(result,"result_%d"%i))
        output.write("\n")
```

Comment: Your constraint makes this impossible without writing your own code printer due to [SymPy issue 8997](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8997). Be aware that your C compiler can handle this itself for sufficiently high optimisation flags (see last comments on the previous link). Your C compiler may also be able to take care of the CSE.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Ok, Constraint was removed,  and yes the compiler can do it but if an human  write an script to emit the code automatically, why not do it?

Comment: *if an human write an script to emit the code automatically, why not do it?* – for the same reason that you do not manually write your C code. Anyway, I may write an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The least painful way is arguably to use the lower-level `ccode` routine (and then create the surrounding C boilerplate as desired):

```
from sympy.printing import ccode
from sympy import symbols, cse, numbered_symbols

x,y,z, B1, B2, B3, B4 = symbols('x y z B1 B2 B3 B4 ')
results = [3.0*B2 + 8.0*B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + 4.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + B3*z**2 + B4*x**4 + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2, 7.0*B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + y**2) + B4*x**3*y + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2, B3*x*y + 8.0*B3*x*z + B3*(x**2 + z**2) + B4*x**3*z + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + 3.0*B3*x*y + B3*x*z + 8.0*B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*y**2 + B4*x*y**3 + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*y**4 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2, B3*x*y + 2*B3*x*z + 6.0*B3*y*z + B3*(y**2 + z**2) + B4*x**2*y*z + B4*x*y**2*z + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*y**3*z + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3, 3.0*B2 + B3*x**2 + B3*x*y + 3.0*B3*x*z + B3*y**2 + 3.0*B3*y*z + 8.0*B3*z**2 + B4*x**2*z**2 + B4*x*y*z**2 + B4*x*z**3 + B4*y**2*z**2 + B4*y*z**3 + B4*z**4]
CSE_results = cse(results,numbered_symbols("helper_"))

with open("snippet.c", "w") as output:
    for helper in CSE_results[0]:
        output.write("double ")
        output.write(ccode(helper[1],helper[0]))
        output.write("\n")

    for i,result in enumerate(CSE_results[1]):
        output.write(ccode(result,"result_%i"%i))
        output.write("\n")
```

This will generate a file `snippet.c` that looks like this:

```c
double helper_0 = pow(z, 2);
double helper_1 = B3*helper_0;
[…]
double helper_31 = helper_14*helper_25;
result_0 = B4*pow(x, 4) + helper_1 + 8.0*helper_10 + […];
[…]
result_5 = B4*pow(z, 4) + 8.0*helper_1 + helper_18 + […];
```

Comment: I suspect you meant 'least painful'.

Comment: @BillBell: No, I am a masochist. (Fixed.)

Comment: We're all masochists on here. That doesn't count.